# virtual host in ubuntu not work

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I created a virtual host in `/etc/apache2/site-available/mysite.local` with this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in `/etc/hosts` :

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.3    mysite.local
```

but when i go to `mysite.local` it shows `localhost`!
what's the problem?

Comment: am also having issues, i think something needs to be changed to host file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is according to reloading apache2 service, I must reload apache as a sudoer.

I must use `sudo service apache2 reload` instead of `service apache2 reload`.