# creating a virtual host

Tags: laravel, virtualhost

I want to create a virtual host for my application i got some tutorials of how to setup a virtual host but still i am having issues with it, first i create a new file in the /etc/apache2/sites-avalable/popinbay.dev   This is the popinbay.dev file please note that i am using ubuntu 14.04

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin udemesamuel256@gmail.com
    ServerName popibay.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel4        
   </VirtualHost>
```

then i edited the /etc/hosts and added this line

```
    127.0.0.1       popibay.dev
```

then i did a sudo service apache2 reload based on this tutorial [virtual host in ubuntu not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936026/virtual-host-in-ubuntu-not-work?rq=1)
But the problem is it still goes to the default localhost page instaed of the laravel4 page.

Comment: `/etc/apache2/sites-avalable/popinbay.dev` the "sites-avalable" is a typo right?

Comment: @Unnawut yes it is...

Answer (score 2):

You are using a "Name-based Virtual Hosts".

From Apache docs on [Using Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using):

> To use name-based virtual hosting, you must designate the IP address (and possibly port) on the server that will be accepting requests for the hosts. This is configured using the NameVirtualHost directive. In the normal case where any and all IP addresses on the server should be used, you can use * as the argument to NameVirtualHost.

Try add `NameVirtualHost *:80` to the top of your configuration, then restart your apache. E.g.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin udemesamuel256@gmail.com
    ServerName popibay.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel4        
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that you might need to change your DocumentRoot to `/var/www/laravel4/public`. That's where your http server should point to by default in Laravel projects.

Comment: i tried what you said but it id not work it still going to the localhost index.html file

Comment: @ubilli try Abhineet's answer too. It could be what he said or combination of both his answer and mine. Sometimes I need to restart my browser too for the updated `/etc/hosts` file to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You added virtual host file in sites-available folder but didn't *Enabled* it.

Use

```
sudo a2ensite virtuatl_host.conf
```

In your case,

```
sudo a2ensite popibay.dev.conf
```

And then,

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: ➜ sites-available>sudo a2ensite popinbay.dev
ERROR: Site popinbay.dev does not exist!
➜ sites-available>

Comment: Are you sure that your conf name is `popinbay.dev`? If not, then replace the `popinbay.dev` with that name

Comment: this is my command line    ➜ sites-available>ls
000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf  popibay.dev
➜ sites-available>

Comment: @Abihineet Verma it is popibay.dev  not popinbay.dev

Comment: Got it. It's popibay.dev, you mentioned popinbat.dev in your question. Anyways use `sudo a2ensite popibay.dev` instead of `sudo a2ensite popinbay.dev`

Comment: ➜ sites-available>sudo a2ensite popibay.dev
ERROR: Site popibay.dev does not exist!
➜ sites-available>
@Abihineet Verma

Comment: rename `popibay.dev` to `popibay.dev.conf` : each virtual host file should be ended in `.conf`

Comment: Guys, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591889/site-does-not-exist-error-for-a2ensite. Could be to do with file extension

Comment: It's a bit strange, have you got the same error? Anyway, follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts , it will guide you step by step.